# Strip whitespace from fields before Angular post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to strip all whitespace from three fields (leading, trailing and between characters) that will be sent to the backend by Angular post request. Data is passed from the form data object. Currently I have solved it by creating custom deserializer for Jackson that does the job, but I would be more interested to remove them before they reach my Spring backend.

```
function insertNumber(form, result) {
    NumberSequence.save({"type": form.$name}, form.$data,
        success(result),
        error(form, result));
}
```

Data here contains 3 fields:

- start
- end
- number

I would need to filter all of them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: start.trim(), end.trim(), number.trim()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS provides an `ng-trim` directive for doing this see the [input directive documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/directive/input). If this isn't what you were looking for, then using a regular expression as suggested by @KyleK.

Comment: My requirement extends to not only leading and trailing spaces, but also to anything between words. Unfortunately ng-trim doesn't provide it, thanks anyway, possibly will have to write my own similar directive.

Comment: Isn't it easier to use form validation for this kind of thing? User experience suffers when you change what data the user types in...

Comment: Actually reading the requirement again. Think it was made up by me to remove spaces between words/numbers as well. They only require leading and trailing so trim by default should do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your function:

```
for (var i in form.$data) {
    form.$data[i] = form.$data[i].replace(/^\s+/g, '').replace(/\s+$/g, '');
}
```

Or use .trim() but natively not supported before IE 9.

Comment: Not much of a fan for that kind of approach. Also $data object can have undefined fields and it makes the code too ugly. Thanks though.